# Explanations for Ctrl-x Ctrl-d in "insert mode"

Tags: vim

Could someone explain to me this combination how it works?  (the manual page is not helpful at all!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expects that you are writing code. For example if you have a file with these contents, and the cursor at the _ position

```
#define hello world
and h_
```

and you are in insert mode, then typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> will complete it to

```
#define hello world
and hello_
```

The online help tells you a little of this with [`:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-D`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html?#i_CTRL-X_CTRL-D)

Comment: So, this combination is only suitable for C source codes?

Comment: No, you can alter the definition of how a macro is defined, see `:help define` for examples including javascript and C++.

Comment: Aah...so, the macros concern programming languages? because at the beginning I thought that "macros" referred to vim macros!

Comment: A reasonable mistake, but yes this is all to do with programming languages and not vim macros. If you are happy with the answer then please consider accepting it (perhaps after waiting a day in case a better answer comes along).